# Assessing conditions on list of solutions

Tags: list-manipulation, condition

I have a list of solutions from `Solve[]` in the form

```
sol ={
{A-> 3 a, B-> 2 -b,C-> a*b},
{A-> 5 a, B-> 2 +b,C-> a/b},
{A-> 0.5 a, B-> 2 b,C-> a-b}
};
```

where `a` and `b` are as yet unspecified parameters.

I would like to assess the truth of various conditions on each solution/row (evaluated after specifying `a` and `b`):  a condition for the `A`'s, a condition on each `B`'s, etc...

For example, `A>0` for all `A`'s:

```
In[]:= #>0 &/@ sol[[;;,1,2]]
Out[]= {3 a>0, 5 a>0, 0.5 a>0}
```

`0 <= B < 1` for all `B`'s:

```
In[]:= Bs=0 <= #< 1 &/@ sol[[;;,2,2]]
Out[]= {0<=2-b<1, 0<=2+b<1, 0<=2 b<1}
```

and `C > 0` for the `C`'s:

```
In[]:=  Cs=#> 0 &/@ sol[[;;,3,2]]

Out[]= {a b>0, a/b>0, a-b>0}
```

Thus, together :

```
In[]:= solCond=Transpose[{As,Bs, Cs}];
solCond//TableForm

Out[]//TableForm= 
3 a>0   0<=2-b<1    a b>0
5 a>0   0<=2+b<1    a/b>0
0.5 a>0 0<=2 b<1    a-b>0
```

I then want to evaluate at a given set of parameter values

```
In[]:= par = {a-> 2, b-> 2};
solCond/.par//TableForm

Out[]//TableForm= 
True    True    True
True    False   True
True    False   False
```

and then assess whether all conditions are satisfied by each solution.

```
In[]:= And@@@solCond/.par
Out[]= {True,False,False}
```

My ultimate goal is to supply the result to `RegionPlot[]`.

```
In[]:= RegionPlot[
Evaluate[And@@@solCond],
{a,0,2},
{b,0,2},
PlotLegends->"Expressions"]
```

My list of solutions is relatively large (5 x 28) and I wish to assess different sets of conditions to produce different plots.  I  therefore desire a more efficient (concise) and general way of specifying and applying the conditions on the `A`'s, `B`'s, and `C`'s.  There's got to be a simple way to write a function to apply to each row of `sol` that takes in the conditions as arguments, but I am naive enough about Mathematica's syntax that I can't figure out how to use `Slots[]` or `Parts[]` appropriately.

Comment: Can't you use something like `A>0 && 0<=B<=1 && C>0 /. sol`?

Comment: Wow.  I knew the answer had to be simple, but I didn't think it would be *that* simple!

Comment: @LukasLang Please submit as answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of `Solve` is designed to be directly used as replacement rules for `Replace` related functions:

```
sol = {{A -> 3 a, B -> 2 - b, C -> a*b}, {A -> 5 a, B -> 2 + b, 
    C -> a/b}, {A -> 0.5 a, B -> 2 b, C -> a - b}};

solCond = A > 0 && 0 <= B <= 1 && C > 0 /. sol
(* {3 a > 0 && 0 <= 2 - b <= 1 && a b > 0, 
 5 a > 0 && 0 <= 2 + b <= 1 && a/b > 0, 
 0.5 a > 0 && 0 <= 2 b <= 1 && a - b > 0} *)

par = {a -> 2, b -> 2};
solCond /. par
(* {True, False, False} *)
```